# Simplest Blogger Template. (BlogSpot)

Tags: html, css, blogger, blogspot

I am looking for simplest blogger template that i can make with simple code. I have no idea of that. I don't want to use any JavaScript, CSS and all unnecessary stuff.

Final page should look like this.

http://blackberry.falconmediaworks.com/

Comment: Just upload the files to your server, nothing else needed

Comment: Why don't you use the simplest template in Blogger?

Comment: That's not the simplest template. I know there may be other template , more simpler one.

Comment: The link you gave (to show how the final page should look) resulted in a 500 Internal Server Error when I tried it just now. Is there a screenshot you could post up?

Comment: Please update this question with more screenshot because the link you gave cannot be loaded.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're looking for an empty Blogspot/Blogger template, paste this as template HTML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html b:version='2' class='v2' expr:dir='data:blog.languageDirection' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:b='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/b' xmlns:data='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/data' xmlns:expr='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/expr'>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <b:include data='blog' name='all-head-content'/>
    <title><data:blog.pageTitle/></title>
    <b:skin><![CDATA[   ]]></b:skin>
</head>

<body>
    <b:section class='main' id='main' showaddelement='no'><b:widget id='Blog1' locked='true' title='Blog Posts' type='Blog'/></b:section>
</body>

</html>
```

This gives you a blog that is populated with only and just the blog posts. If you want to add additional elements, such as a list of archived blog posts, use the layout editor or refer to [this page](http://support.google.com/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=46888) for their tags.